# separate 10 consecutive numbers which are without space

Tags: r

My data is in given format-

[Please find attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRGOv.png)

How to get 10 consecutive numbers in a new column? Thanks in advance

```
structure(list(Datetime = c("12/05/2017 08:22", "12/05/2017 08:32", 
"12/05/2017 08:32", "12/05/2017 08:44", "12/05/2017 08:44", "12/05/2017 08:47", 
"12/05/2017 08:48", "12/05/2017 08:49", "12/05/2017 08:51"), 
    Message = c("â€ª+91 98122 92212â€ < >", "â€ª+91 97799 88581â€        9417673824   363006", 
    "â€ª+91 97799 88581â€ < >", "â€ª+91 99969 42327â€      9990175777", 
    "â€ª+91 99969 42327â€ < >", "â€ª+91 98101 62461â€", "â€ª+91 98156 37302â€", 
    "â€ª+91 98156 37302â€ < >", "â€ª+91 88720 30191â€       602013  9317588213"
    )), .Names = c("Datetime", "Message"), row.names = c("352", 
"353", "354", "355", "356", "357", "358", "365", "366"), class = "data.frame")
```

Expected output:

```
Message2 = c("" "", "" 9417673824"", "" "", ""9990175777"", "" "", """", """", """", ""9317588213""))
```

Comment: Please show a small example using `dput` and expected output instead of images as we cannot copy from image

Comment: Show an expected output and some R code of what you have so far.

Comment: If that's a data frame something like "my.df$Nr<-seq(from=20,to=29,by=1) ". Note that you've got rownames too.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: I want to separate the 10 consecutive numbers (without space) from column message to a new column

Comment: Update your post with the expected output for your example data. i.e. what happens to row 1 Message  `" â€ª+91 98122 92212â€ < >"`?

Comment: I don't want to change message column data, i just want if there are 10 consecutive numbers without space in Message column then paste the same to column Message2 else blank

Comment: Message = c(""â€ª+91 98122 92212â€ < >"", ""â€ª+91 97799 88581â€        9417673824   363006"", 
    ""â€ª+91 97799 88581â€ < >"", ""â€ª+91 99969 42327â€      9990175777"", 
    ""â€ª+91 99969 42327â€ < >"", ""â€ª+91 98101 62461â€"", ""â€ª+91 98156 37302â€"", 
    ""â€ª+91 98156 37302â€ < >"", ""â€ª+91 88720 30191â€       602013  9317588213""
    )),   Message2 = c("" "", "" 9417673824"", 
    "" "", ""9990175777"", 
    "" "", """", """", 
    """", ""9317588213""))

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(df$Message, '\\D+'), function(x){x <- x[nchar(x) == 10]; if(length(x) == 0) NA else x})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `stringi` package,

```
library(stringi)
unlist(stri_extract_all_regex(df$Message, '([0-9]+){10}'))

#[1] NA           "9417673824" NA           "9990175777" NA           NA           NA           NA           "9317588213"
```

via Base R,

```
sapply(strsplit(trimws(gsub('\\D+', ' ', df$Message)), ' '), 
                                                        function(i) i[nchar(i) == 10])

or

sapply(strsplit(trimws(gsub('\\D+', ' ', df$Message)), ' '), function(i) 
                                replace(i[nchar(i) == 10], !length(i[nchar(i) == 10]), NA))
#[1] NA           "9417673824" NA           "9990175777" NA           NA           NA           NA           "9317588213"
```